# Fancy Box for Html Pages

Tags: html, fancybox, fancybox-2, box

I'm looking for a "fancy box" esque solution for text.
I'd like my end user to click an image on a page, and have a text page come up over the original presentation.
My initial approach was to use fancy box, and instead of loading an image the computer would load an .html page.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: Fancybox can display whatever you want - have a look at the iframe example at fancyapps.com/fancybox

Comment: for external webpages, use `iframe` type in either of these formats http://stackoverflow.com/a/27193448/1055987